# MVC Binding Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Project.

I have questions in a database that I want my users to answer.  I have them in the database because they need to be able to be dynamic.  The user needs to submit an answer for each question.  So when the view displays, it shows the question and a textbox for each question.

What would the best way to go about doing this as I **do not** want to hard code in the question like @Html.textBox("Question1") etc.

1. Question 1    [**__*textbox1*___**]
2. Question 2    [**__*textbox2*___**]

... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably have a ViewModel that contains a collection of a custom QuestionResponder type.

```
IEnumerable<IQuestionResponder> Questions{get;set;}

public interface IQuestionResponder{
    Guid QuestionId{get;set;}
    string Question{get;set;}
    string Answer{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can create the display items you require for your new view model.

```
@for(var i = 0; i <= questionList .Count; i++)
{
   @Model.Questions.ToList()[i].Question
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Questions.ToList()[i].Answer)
}
```

Alternartively you can create an EditorTemplate to avoid looping in your view:

Insdie `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` add a new view called `QuestionResponder` (the name of your custom class).

Inside that template you can then add:

```
@model MyApp.Models.QuestionResponder
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer)
</div>
```

While you'll then call from your original view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's builtin way of doing that in MVC. Very simple way, by the way. There are many alternatives, take a look at [this article by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) to inspect them all. One of those is with dictionaries. Quesion.Id will be key, Answer will be value

*Sample:*

First, create appropriate ViewModels

```
    public class AnswerQuestionViewModel
    {
        public Quesion Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
    public class Quesion //
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // Maybe some other properties.
    }
```

Inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/`, create editor that will render Editor.

```
@model Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Question.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer)
```

And `~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<ControllerInspectorTest.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{              
    @Html.EditorForModel();

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>                          
}
```

And when you create post action, parameter will be filled in

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AnswerQuestions(IEnumerable<AnswerQuestionViewModel> quesions)
 {
     // questions parameter is filled in correctly 
     //do save job;
 }
```

Note that question parameter can by type of `IList` or `List` too